# Aligning multiple tables vertically from the top

Tags: tables

I need to

1. align all four tables on their top (currently it looks like they are all aligned by center).
2. have the vertical line separating "funct" in each table not to be interrupted.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\textwidth= 5.00in
\textheight= 7.4in
\topmargin = 30pt
\evensidemargin=0pt
\oddsidemargin=55pt
\headsep=17pt
\parskip=.8pt
\parindent=12pt
\font\smallit=cmti10
\font\smalltt=cmtt10
\font\smallrm=cmr9

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,enumitem} 
\usepackage{subcaption,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h] 
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\small 
\caption{Examples} 
\label{tab:4subt_2}
\begin{subtable}{0.35\textwidth}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccccc|c}
\toprule
$aa$ & $bb$ & $cc$ & $dd$  & $ee$ & fu\\
\midrule
1& 2& 3& 4& 5& $1,2,3,4 = [5] \setminus \{6\}$\\
1& 2& 3& 4& 5& $1,2,3,4 = [5] \setminus \{6\}$\\
1& 2& 3& 4& 5& $1,2,3,4 = [5] \setminus \{6\}$\\
1& 2& 3& 4& 5& $1,2,3,4 = [5] \setminus \{6\}$\\
1& 2& 3& 4& 5& $1,2,3,4 = [5] \setminus \{6\}$\\
\hline
1& 2& 3& 4& 5& $1,2,3,4 = [5] \setminus \{6\}$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{subtable}
\hfill
\begin{subtable}{0.22\textwidth}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccccc|c}
\toprule
$aa$ & $bb$ & $cc$ & $dd$  & $ee$ & fu\\
\midrule
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2, 3\\
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2, 3\\
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2, 3\\
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2, 3\\
\hline
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2, 3\\
\hline
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2, 3\\
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2, 3\\
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2, 3\\
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2, 3\\
\hline
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2, 3\\
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2, 3\\
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2, 3\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{subtable}
\hfill
\begin{subtable}{0.2\textwidth}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccccc|c}
\toprule
$aa$ & $bb$ & $cc$ & $dd$  & $ee$ & fu\\
\midrule
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2\\
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2\\
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2\\
\hline
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{subtable}
\hfill
\begin{subtable}{0.18\textwidth}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccccc|c} 
\toprule
$aa$ & $bb$ & $cc$ & $dd$  & $ee$ & fu\\
\midrule
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1\\
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{subtable}
\hfill
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: never use a primitive font assignment such as  `\font\smallit` in latex!!!  but `\begin{tabular*}[t]` will make the tables align on their first row

Answer (score 3):

As @DavidCarlisle has already suggested in a comment, just change all four instances of

```
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}
```

to

```
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}[t]
```

The `t` alignment specifier tells LaTeX that the four `tabular*` environments should be aligned along their top lines.

Incidentally, it's not a good idea at all to employ vertical rules in `tabular*` environments with `\tabcolsep` set to zero.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\textwidth= 5.00in
\textheight= 7.4in
\topmargin = 30pt
\evensidemargin=0pt
\oddsidemargin=55pt
\headsep=17pt
\parskip=.8pt
\parindent=12pt
%\font\smallit=cmti10
%\font\smalltt=cmtt10
%\font\smallrm=cmr9

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,enumitem} 
\usepackage{subcaption,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h] 
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\small 
\caption{Examples} 
\label{tab:4subt_2}
\begin{subtable}{0.35\textwidth}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}[t]{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccccc|c}
\toprule
$aa$ & $bb$ & $cc$ & $dd$  & $ee$ & fu\\
\midrule
1& 2& 3& 4& 5& $1,2,3,4 = [5] \setminus \{6\}$\\
1& 2& 3& 4& 5& $1,2,3,4 = [5] \setminus \{6\}$\\
1& 2& 3& 4& 5& $1,2,3,4 = [5] \setminus \{6\}$\\
1& 2& 3& 4& 5& $1,2,3,4 = [5] \setminus \{6\}$\\
1& 2& 3& 4& 5& $1,2,3,4 = [5] \setminus \{6\}$\\
\hline
1& 2& 3& 4& 5& $1,2,3,4 = [5] \setminus \{6\}$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{subtable}%
\hfill
\begin{subtable}{0.22\textwidth}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}[t]{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccccc|c}
\toprule
$aa$ & $bb$ & $cc$ & $dd$  & $ee$ & fu\\
\midrule
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2, 3\\
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2, 3\\
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2, 3\\
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2, 3\\
\hline
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2, 3\\
\hline
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2, 3\\
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2, 3\\
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2, 3\\
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2, 3\\
\hline
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2, 3\\
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2, 3\\
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2, 3\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{subtable}%
\hfill
\begin{subtable}{0.2\textwidth}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}[t]{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccccc|c}
\toprule
$aa$ & $bb$ & $cc$ & $dd$  & $ee$ & fu\\
\midrule
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2\\
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2\\
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2\\
\hline
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{subtable}%
\hfill
\begin{subtable}{0.18\textwidth}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}[t]{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccccc|c} 
\toprule
$aa$ & $bb$ & $cc$ & $dd$  & $ee$ & fu\\
\midrule
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1\\
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{subtable}%
\hfill
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: is there a way to make the separating line before "funct" to go without interruption?

Comment: @Vika - Since your initial code makes use of the `booktabs` package and its line-drawing macros, I assumed you knew what you're doing. In particular, that you were aware of following rule posited by the package's author: "Never, ever use vertical rules". You should look into it.

Answer (score 2):

- Rules defined in the `booktabs` package are not intendent to be use in tables with vertical lines.
- For removing this gaps, you have several possibilities. For example redefine rules and add add vertical spaces by use of the `cellspace` package, ... or use `tabularray` package is is shown below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\textwidth= 5.00in
\textheight= 7.4in
\topmargin = 30pt
\evensidemargin=0pt
\oddsidemargin=55pt
\headsep=17pt
\parskip=.8pt
\parindent=12pt

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, booktabs}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,enumitem}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\small
\caption{Examples}
\label{tab:4subt_2}
\begin{subtable}{0.36\textwidth}
\begin{tblr}[t]{colsep= 2pt,
             colspec = {@{} *{5}{X[c]}|Q[c,mode=math] @{}},
             row{1}  = {mode=math}
             }
    \toprule
aa & bb & cc & dd  & ee & \text{fu}\\
    \midrule
1   & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 1,2,3,4 = [5] \setminus \{6\}    \\
1   & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 1,2,3,4 = [5] \setminus \{6\}    \\
1   & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 1,2,3,4 = [5] \setminus \{6\}    \\
1   & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 1,2,3,4 = [5] \setminus \{6\}    \\
1   & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 1,2,3,4 = [5] \setminus \{6\}    \\
    \hline
1   & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 1,2,3,4 = [5] \setminus \{6\}     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{subtable}%
\hfill
\begin{subtable}{0.23\textwidth}
\begin{tblr}[t]{colsep= 2pt,
             colspec = {@{} *{5}{X[c]}|c @{}},
             row{1}  = {mode=math}
             }
    \toprule
aa & bb & cc & dd  & ee & \text{fu} \\
    \midrule
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2, 3\\
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2, 3\\
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2, 3\\
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2, 3\\
    \hline
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2, 3\\
\hline
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2, 3\\
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2, 3\\
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2, 3\\
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2, 3\\
    \hline
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2, 3\\
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2, 3\\
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2, 3\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{subtable}%
\hfill
\begin{subtable}{0.20\textwidth}
\begin{tblr}[t]{colsep= 2pt,
             colspec = {@{} *{5}{X[c]}|c @{}},
             row{1}  = {mode=math}
             }
    \toprule
aa & bb & cc & dd  & ee & \text{fu}   \\
    \midrule
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2\\
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2\\
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2\\
    \hline
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1, 2\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{subtable}%
\hfill
\begin{subtable}{0.18\textwidth}
\begin{tblr}[t]{colsep= 2pt,
             colspec = {@{} *{5}{X[c]}|c @{}},
             row{1}  = {mode=math}
             }
    \toprule
aa & bb & cc & dd  & ee & \text{fu}\\
    \midrule
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1\\
1 &2 &3 &4 &5  & 1\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{subtable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]